# Are there other ways to acquire Port Noon Anecdote?

Tags: cultist-simulator

Apparently, the only way to acquire Port Noon Anecdote is by going thru the Peacock's Door and merging
2 Vagabond's Map.

Are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the easiest way.  You can get one from the book, "The Voyages of Ferninshun of Oreal" which is usually found in Lagun's Tomb.  You can also start with lower-level lore and do lots and lots of merging.

Comment: My guess is it really the only simple way to acquire the lore after a huge discussion I had here: https://www.reddit.com/r/weatherfactory/comments/oganph/is_the_only_way_to_acquire_port_noon_anecdote/